# Python 3.6.1 and tkinter askdirectory failing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

While testing this section of script it was apparent there is something deeper wrong with python or tkinter. The askdirectory is nice as it allows the user to use the GUI to select both a source and destination path. So before I started wanted to test out just the selection of source path following by printing out every file found. My first error was easily bypassed using "try and exception" as shown in the code. For now bypassing is fine till an answer is finalized for the second error reported from this basic script

Code:

```
import os
enterSearchPath=str("C:/")
print(enterSearchPath)
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(enterSearchPath):              
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            print(filename)                 
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            print("UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' ")
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect it is because python cannot handle this kind of amount of task

Comment: Was looking for someone to run the code on their machine multiple times as now I am finding sometimes it runs through completion and other times it does not. Windows 8.1 python 3.6.1